# How to use the Shape Designer Tool after warping a shape? On Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, tools

I would like to use the Shape Designer Tool, after deforming my shape, but this is what it shows me, it's possible? Convert or I don't know, after shape distort. THANKS.

[image]

Comment: Shape Designer tool? What software are you using?

Comment: Illustrator, sorry

Comment: There is no Shape Designer tool in Illustrator. Do you mean the Shape Builder tool?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so to do, what I had to ask, it's very simple, after having deformed your shape, if you want to reunite it or use the Shape Builder tool, you go to {Object > decompose the aspect} and you will have your transformed and converted form. Here's a good continuation

[image]